# NodeJS: Code to execute when server starts

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using a [**MEAN.JS**](http://meanjs.org/) framework ([MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/), [**ExpressJS**](http://expressjs.com/), [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [**NodeJS**](https://nodejs.org/en/)) to build an app.

Using [**Socket.IO**](http://socket.io/); I'm keeping in MongoDB User schema if the user is connected or not.

```
//Connect
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    connectToChat(true);

    //Disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        connectToChat(false);
    });

    function connectToChat(isConnect){
        var user = socket.request.user;
        var numberOfSocketClients = Object.keys(io.sockets.adapter.rooms[user.id] || {}).length;
        if(isConnect || (!isConnect && numberOfSocketClients===0)) {
            User.findOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user.id)})
                .exec(function (err, doc) {
                    if(!err && doc){
                        doc.isConnected = isConnect;
                        doc.save(callback);
                    }
                });
        }

});
```

This **works well** in all cases **except when server is stopped**... When server is restarted all the user should be not connected by default but there are some connected users saved in MongoDB User schema.

Okey, I understand that stop the server is a rare case because I'm using [**Forever**](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)... But, **is there a good methodology to execute a code in ExpressJS only when the server is restarted?** I tried to execute a code in `server.js`file but all the sessions execute this code and it's not that I want.

*Thank you very much!*

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the ExpressJs listening event. It is fired on boot, once the server is ready to accept connections.

```
app.on('listening', function () {
    // server ready to accept connections here
});
```

Where app is your express server.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this now!

Comment: Don't work for me... Can you send me some documentation reference? I don't find any documentation about it... Thank you!

Comment: @AralRoca - Here is the Node.js docs. Express creates a node js server so all node events are fired too: https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.13/api/net.html#net_event_listening